# htaccess eliminate www then redirect all non subdomains traffic to https

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've tried 10 various configurations of this, all found as answers here, but all I end up with is a redirect loop.

My latest try is as follows:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.test.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://test.com/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(.*?)\.test.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

With the first two  lines I'm eliminating www

I'm then checking there is no subdomain, and if https is already set, then I'm redirecting.

Finally I'm checking for existing files etc and sending all traffic via index.php

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}  !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}  !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}  !-f
RewriteRule .* index.php?%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

Can anyone spot the obvious mistake?

Comment: Are you using any CMS/PHP framework?

Comment: We've baked our own MVC framework so all page requests need to route through index.php

Comment: With above rules in place open your URL in Firebug and see what you get in Net tab?

Comment: Just a whole heap of 301 redirects

Comment: www is redirected to non-www, then it does switch to https, but then it just keeps looping

Comment: Right so something is redirecting back to http and `www`. Is it your framework?

Comment: Aah you set me on the right lines. It now works except the RewiteRule isn't ignoring subdomains and is still sending them to https

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This rule will ignore subdomain for `http->https` redirection:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.test\.com$
RewriteRule ^ https://test.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
```

**PS:** This will replace your first www removal rule also.